# How to ignore certain parts of a line in text file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, markov-decision-process

I'm attempting to extract the numerical information from an input.txt file I have below.

```
    size : 5 4

    walls : 2 2 , 2 3

    reward : -0.04

    transition_probabilities : 0.8 0.1 0.1 0

    discount_rate : 0.85

    epsilon : 0.001
```

As you can see, some of the lines contain integers, some contain lists of integers, and some contain lists of tuples. However, I am specifically looking to be able to check what a line starts with (using the startswith() function) and then IGNORING the part that I am checking. Below is what I have so far:

```
    f = open("mdp_input.txt", "r")

    for line in f:
        if line.lower().startswith("size : "):
            size_list = line.split(" ")
            cols = int(size_list[2])
            rows = int(size_list[1])
        elif line.lower().startswith("walls : "):
            walls = str(input("walls : "))
            walls_list = walls.split(",")
            for item in walls_list:
                tuple = tuple(map(int, item.split(' ')))
                walls.append(tuple)
```

I'm just not quite sure how to essentially ignore the words before the colon and only look at the numbers after it, especially considering that each line is being parsed differently based on what I need from it (integers, a list, a list of tuples, etc). Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of the `split` function to first split your line by colon taking the second element(i.e the parts after the colon), then split it by what ever field separator you need for that use case. also i not in your code you called a variable tuple, that will overwrite the tupe function so you wont be able to use it again. Always create variables with names that dont conflict with python inbuilt names.

```
data = """size : 5 4
walls : 2 2 , 2 3
reward : -0.04
transition_probabilities : 0.8 0.1 0.1 0
discount_rate : 0.85
epsilon : 0.001"""

for line in data.splitlines():
    if line.startswith('size'):
        col, row = [int(num) for num in line.split(':')[1].strip().split()]
        print(col, row)
    elif line.startswith('walls'):
        walls = []
        for wall in line.split(':')[1].strip().split(','):
            walls.append([int(num) for num in wall.split()])
        print(walls)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
5 4
[(2, 2), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond earlier, but thank you for the help! It makes sense to split first by the colon and then split the second element by the desired separator

Answer (score 0):

What about starting the code by splitting it with the ":"? Then you can check the first half for the identifier and the second half for the data.

```
f = open("mdp_input.txt", "r")

for line in f:
    info = line.split(":")

if info[0].startswith("size"):
    size_list = info[1].split(" ")
    cols = int(size_list[2])
    rows = int(size_list[1])
elif info[0].startswith("walls"):
    walls_list = info[1].split(",")
    for item in walls_list:
        tuple = tuple(map(int, item.split(' ')))
        walls.append(tuple)
```